# how to reset an array index? actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, actionscript

I got a problem with processing an array in actionScript. I removed the last element of an array through `array.pop()`. After that I would like to put this removed display-object back to the beginning of the array: `array.unshift(object)`. The object is now the first element of the array but it got still its old label (number of the last element). Therefor I can't update the position (graphically) of the display object. Is it possible to "reindex" the array?

Comment: how does this "object" look like? is Label a property of "Object"?

Comment: the label is a number "i", because the array will be processed in a for-loop. therefore the unshifting looks like this: array.unshift(array[i]);
the array[i] will keep its label when i put it again at the beggining of the array, how to set the label to zero again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `pop`ped element will not keep it's index, since it will be taken out of the array. If you're trying to `unshift(array[i])` after `pop`ping `array[i]`, you get an error for referencing an index that no longer exists.

In order to do what you're describing, you can say `array.unshift(array.pop())` and then reference the moved element at `array[0]`.

I used the above method when I created an endlessly looping slideshow.

Edit.

It seems I misunderstood your problem slightly. IIRC it is not possible to manipulate an array you're traversing over.

Please post the snippet you're having trouble with for a more educated answer.